# How to Import Old code from a Different namespace into My Current Project?

Tags: c#, namespaces

I want to use old code in a new project in c#.

This is the old code. It is saved in an arbitrary folder on my PC.

```
namespace OldCode{
    class HellowWorld
    {
        public static void SayHello()
        {
            Console.writeline("Hello World")
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use this in a new project called new code.

```
using OldCode (?)

namespace NewCode
{
    class SayHelloNew
    {
        HelloWorld.SayHello();
    }
}
```

My question is, how do I link to my old project? Did I do it right with *using OldCode?* Or is there some other dependency file I need to set up?

Answer (score 0):

That is almost correct. The colon (`:`) needs to be removed from the `namespace` declaration and to access the `HelloWorld` class externally, it must be public.

OldCode\HelloWorld.cs

```
namespace OldCode
{
    public class HelloWorld
    {
        public static void SayHello()
        {
            Console.writeline("Hello World")
        }
    }
}
```

NewCode\SayHelloNew.cs

```
using OldCode;

namespace NewCode
{
    class SayHelloNew
    {
        HelloWorld.SayHello();
    }
}
```

You will also need to ensure the compiler has access to `OldCode` on compilation, or, if using Visual Studio, add a Reference to the `OldCode` project in the `NewCode` project.

[Add references in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-references-by-using-the-reference-manager?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Thanks will, fixed the colon issue. How do I make sure the compiler has access to old code? How do I add the reference to `OldCode` in the `NewCode` namespace? I am using visual studio.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a link on how to do that. Good luck with your coding journey! :)

Comment: Also, technically the code for `SayHelloNew` is invalid. The call to `HelloWorld.SayHello()` needs to be within a method or the return value (in this case, null as there is no return statement in the function) stored in a variable.

Comment: Thanks, couldn't think of the syntax off the top of my head. How do I mark your answer as correct?

Comment: I'm not sure you can because you're a new member and don't have enough reputation, however your thanks is enough for me.

Comment: You can't call SayHello() in the class block: 
    `class SayHelloNew
    {
        HelloWorld.SayHello();// error`

Comment: Thanks Peyman. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yeap, Let me describe for you,
First you should make **public** your class to access it in other sources by adding `public` modifier like this:

```
using System;
namespace Stackoverflow.OldCode
{
    public class HelloWorld    // <----------- make it public
    {
        public static void SayHello()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!!!");
        }
    }
}
```

Then I suggest adding a prefix in every other `namespace`s to show they are related to each other, like

```
namespace Stackoverflow.OldCode;
namespace Stackoverflow.NewCode;
```

The `NewCode` project and the `OldCode` should be in one solution, if not now, right-click on the solution name and choose: `Add>New Project...` or `Add>Existing Project...`

[image: add new project]

Then you should add the `NewCode` project as a reference to the `OldCode` project:

## step1:

## [image: add refrence]
step2:

[image: choose the old proj]

Now you can access old project methods easily, like:

```
using Stackoverflow.OldCode;   // <---- add the reference
namespace Stackoverflow.NewCode
{
    class SayHelloNew
    {
        public static void SomeRandomName()
        {
            HelloWorld.SayHello();  // <----- call it 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Peyman - I'm learning the OOP core principles in more detail at the moment and have a question. If the code I want to include is old, it wouldn't necessarily have the same namespace prefix. In your opinion, doesn't it break the OOP open-closed principle to then change the namespace for another project, or the DRY principle to copy it into the new project to change the namespace for this project? I can understand encapsulating the old code in new code under a new namespace, but changing it seems wrong to me somehow.

Comment: Actually, you're right. you do not have to rename your existing project's `namespace`... I suggest if you want to create a new one as a `naming convention` make a prefix. you can add any existing project with any namespace to your solution and add it as a reference to your old projects like I explained above.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer you can mark it as accepted by clicking on ✔️=>✅ near beside my answer, have fun :))  @WillWalsh